# ExpressJS dynamically generated pages - will search engines create listings based on query parameters?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm creating a directory website of local businesses in a geographical area. The hope is that if you search for something like "plumbers in New York City" then you'll see a link to the domain that will show all plumber records in a 10 mile radius from NYC.

Let's say I have routes set up like this:

```
app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.zip) { // Search by zip code
        mongoose.model('cities').find({zipCode: req.query.zip}, function(err, entries) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('location.ejs', {data: entries});
        });
    }
});
```

So, an incoming url like "http://www.example.net/location?zip=10001" would pull records from the 10001 zip code (New York City) and a page will show all entries in that area. It would generate an h1 tag, title, etc with the city associated with the query string zip.

Since the page will dynamically generate based on url parameters, will search engines be able to crawl every possible zip code and create accurate search listings? In other words, are search engines smart enough to have listings like "Companies in New York City" show up from my site based on the above example?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. Search engines may be able to discover new pages by incrementing methods, but it is not an expected or predictable behaviour.

The easiest solution would a page linking to all other pages, thus allowing search engines to discover them.

Once these pages are indexed, visitors should be able to access a page with a URL like "http://www.example.net/location?zip=10001" by the keywords "Companies in New York City".

I would suggest you to also generate a [sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) with [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) and the list of your zip codes.

Comment: Thanks. So simply putting up a page that has links to all relevant zip codes would do the trick?

Comment: Yep, as long as this page itself is discoverable and discovered. You could also put these URLs in a sitemap.xml at the root of your website (standard for search engines) that you could generate automatically with https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap and a list of all your zip codes.